# How do different character encodings change how php does character comparison?

Tags: php, character-encoding

The question is how does php handle different character encodings for character comparisons? I was told 2 things:

You can set the character encoding for php in some .ini file, and
php reads all characters as ascii (another stackoverflow post)

So which is it?

The question stems from the idea of if I have a svg font file and wanted to parse it to do character comparisons from the font with some input (a text file), do I need to be concerned about character encodings or can I do direct character comparisons?

Comment: http://kunststube.net/encoding

Comment: super helpful read

Comment: So, how wrong would I be in saying that some string of binary maps to a character using some encoding, and then some character using some encoding maps to a glyph in some font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in PHP are implemented as arrays of bytes with an integer indicating the length of the buffer. They contain no information about how those bytes translate to characters, if at all (you can even have NUL bytes inside a PHP "string").

So whether a string literal `'á'` in your script is represented by `\xE1` (ISO-8859-1), `\xC3\xA1` (UTF-8, C form) or `\x61\xCC\x81` (UTF-8, D form) depends only on how it is encoded in the script file.

That said, PHP also has a `zend.multibyte` ini setting, which enables parsing source files written in arbitrary encodings (either explicitly declared with `declare(encoding="...")` directive, or detected), in which case string literals might be internally transliterated to PHP's `mbstring.internal_encoding`. That still doesn't change the internal representation of strings your script reads from external files, unless you expliclitly call `mb_convert_encoding()` on those.

Comment: I think I understand this answer and I am fairly certain that it is the correct one after reading the article from comment above, however I feel highly unqualified in marking this as the correct answer.